# Can't listen on public ip port 80 on AWS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a .net core http server that works on local windows and linux machines. When I try to deploy it on AWS, I can't let it listen on its public ip address. Doing so gives me an exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.HttpListenerException: Cannot assign requested address

If I try to listen on its private ip, the programme runs without exception, I cannot send any http request to its public ip address.

I confirm that the security group setting and ufw status show that in both cases, port 80 is allowed. What could be the reason for the problem?

Comment: Do you have any other web server running? Run netstat -a to check.

Comment: @wannadream Unfortunately no. This is a newly launched instance and there is no other server running. netstat -a confirms it.

Comment: Have your tried to contact AWS support?

Comment: Check the source IP in security groups for that particular instance. It should be 0.0.0.0 in case you allow to access from internet

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice, and sorry for forgetting to reply here. It turns out that the instance uses public DNS instead of ip address. Quite a stupid question lol.

Answer (score 0):

When setting the service, you can leave its URL/IP, so it can listen wherever you load it. The code sample below demonstrates this, along with an example of how to inject the URL or the port. It provides the flexibility to load the service dynamically (the arguments are injected via the method's arguments).

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // using NuGet package: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine
        // Build the config from the command line arguments
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

        // a default port
        int port = 5011;
        // receive the port as an input
        port = config.GetValue<int>("port", port);
        // receive the whole URL as an input
        string url = config.GetValue<string>("url");

        // the URL can be *, not necessarily localhost. 
        //It allows flexibility in deploying it in any platform/host.
        url = String.IsNullOrEmpty(url) ? $"http://*:{port}/" : url;

        // initialize the applicative logger
        ILogger logger = InitializeLogger(config);

        // initialize the web host
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .ConfigureServices(log=>
                log.AddSingleton<ILogger>(logger)) // set the applicative logger
            .ConfigureServices(collection=> 
                collection.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)) // send the command line arguments to Startup instance
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls(url) // set the URL that has been composed above 
            .Build();

         Console.WriteLine($"Host is up and running in URL: {url}");

        host.Run();
    }
```